# How can I incorporate subsurface scattering into a custom shader graph?

Tags: unity, shaders, materials, unity-shader-graph

I'm working on some 3D grass in Unity with HDRP (the grass is not a 2D asset on a plane, it's a mesh).

I did a shader to make it move following a tutorial, it works great. I would like to add Subsurface Scattering (SSS), but I can't find any node or tutorial helping me in that way.

[image: Applying SSS material to a base color]

If I could somehow inject the output of this SSS material into my base colour pin, that would solve the problem.

How can I achieve this subsurface scattering look?

Answer (score -1):

See unity boat attack demo with urp it has integrated SSS with shader graph using custom function node

Comment: This answer would be better it if included the relevant portion of that sample, or steps to recreate it. That way the answer remains useful, even if the boat attack demo it describes becomes inaccessible in future.